# Play Console Error: You need approval to use the following Health Connect permissions in your app

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, google-play-console, healthconnect

I am using `react-native-health-connect` package to get user health info from device. everything is working fine, I am getting user's health info and displaying it.

i have given following permission in `AndroidMenifest.json` file to get data.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_ACTIVE_CALORIES_BURNED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_TOTAL_CALORIES_BURNED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_WEIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_HEIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_STEPS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_HEART_RATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_LEAN_BODY_MASS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_BONE_MASS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_BODY_FAT"/>
```

now I am uploading an update to play store and it is giving me following error
[image]

I have gone through the [FAQs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12991134) but I dont understand what should I need to do to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: See similar question: [How can I resolve the "Health Connect permissions approval required in Play Console" error in my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77450970/how-can-i-resolve-the-health-connect-permissions-approval-required-in-play-cons) [This solution works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77450970/how-can-i-resolve-the-health-connect-permissions-approval-required-in-play-cons/77702777#77702777)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the issue is resolved...

first of all, as they mentioned in the error message that "you need approval to use following health connect permissions in your app.", I have requested the access by filling the [Google Health Connect API Request](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1LFjbq1MOCZySpP5eIVkoyzXTanpcGTYQH26lKcrQUJo/viewform?edit_requested=true) form.

#### what was wrong:

I did not mentioned the use of Health connect data types in my privacy policy. then I mentioned, but this info does not explains the full use to the user.

so, I changed the privacy policy like following and replied to them.

##### policy content:

```
Health Connect Data

a. Collection and Usage of Health Data:
We value the privacy and security of our users. Our mobile application requests access to health-related permissions, specifically the ability to read steps and sleep information. This data is collected for the sole purpose of enhancing the user experience and providing features related to health and fitness.

b. Purpose of Health Data Access:
Our app utilizes health-related permissions to track daily steps, and sleep patterns. This data is processed locally on the user's device and is not shared with any third parties.

c. User Consent:
By using our app, you explicitly consent to the collection and usage of health-related data for the purposes outlined in this privacy policy. You have the option to grant or deny these permissions within the app settings.

d. Security Measures:
We implement robust security measures to protect the confidentiality and integrity of health-related data. This includes encryption and secure storage.

e. Data Retention:
We retain health-related data only for as long as necessary to fulfill the purposes outlined in this privacy policy. Users can request the deletion of their data by 

f. Third-Party Services:
Our app does not share health-related data with any third-party services, advertisers, or external entities. We do not engage in the sale or exchange of user data.
```

Note:

- They take 7-10 business days to review the `Google Health Connect API Request` form, and then send a email with approval or rejection with with detail. if rejected you can reply in thread.
- After approval they take 5 business days to enable use of Google Health Connect data types on play Store builds.

Answer (score 4):

I wish it is not a late answer but it may help. According to their FAQ section to read or write access to Health Connect data types, you should make a request through completing the [Developer Declaration Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1LFjbq1MOCZySpP5eIVkoyzXTanpcGTYQH26lKcrQUJo/viewform?edit_requested=true).

Comment: THANK YOU! This was not obvious, and that link was hidden away. I also came here to find this from `react-native-health-connect` package, so I think that package adding documentation explaining you must submit this form would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill declaration form, and it is long process, you have to upload video to show permissions, then google will ask you to have audit of code from thirdparty.