# How can I resolve the "Health Connect permissions approval required in Play Console" error in my Android app?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, healthconnect

I'm developing a Flutter app which uses the [health](https://pub.dev/packages/health) package to use health related data. And while trying to upload android app, during the upload process in Google Play Console, I encountered the error message "You need approval to use the following Health Connect permissions in your app." The permissions listed include

```
android.permission.health.READ_STEPS
android.permission.health.READ_HEART_RATE
android.permission.health.READ_SLEEP
android.permission.health.READ_BLOOD_PRESSURE
android.permission.health.READ_OXYGEN_SATURATION   
android.permission.health.READ_HYDRATION
```

I understand that accessing health data requires approval and we got the approval from the Health Connect by filling the [Developer Declaration Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1LFjbq1MOCZySpP5eIVkoyzXTanpcGTYQH26lKcrQUJo/viewform?edit_requested=true) form, but still error remains the same in Play console. Can someone guide me through the steps to obtain the necessary approval and resolve this issue?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbZXn.png]

Comment: is it resolved? I am facing a similar issue. can you please post your solution if already resolved? I have taken permission from google once. but I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Before going **LIVE** (release), you will need to apply for permissions to access the Health Connect API with Google. Use this [application form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1LFjbq1MOCZySpP5eIVkoyzXTanpcGTYQH26lKcrQUJo/viewform?edit_requested=true).

In the form, you will need to specify which data types you intend to read from Health Connect.

Answer (score 0):

[Stackoverflow response for react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77064586/play-console-error-you-need-approval-to-use-the-following-health-connect-permis)

I just found this on another thread,

You must wait for an answer from google before it works. Let me know if that work.

Answer (score -3):

To apply for access to these permissions, follow these steps:

1. Go to the **Google Play Console** and select your app.
2. Click on "**Features**" and then select "**Health Connect**."
3. Click on the "Request access" button for each permission you need.
4. Provide a clear and concise explanation of why your app needs access to each **permission**.(It is mandatory beacuse of the **Health Connect Access** criteria)
5. Submit your request and **wait for Google's review**.

Once your request is approved, you'll be able to use the requested permissions in your app. Remember to handle these permissions responsibly and respect user privacy.

Comment: Thanks @Satyan but there is no FEATURES option  available in Play console, checked.